# Adding pages/links

Tags: html, css, web

I am writing code to create my first website. I am working hard to start a career as a front-end developer. I am coding right now in HTML/CSS for my site. I have added a list with buttons in the hopes of having each button open a new page. My question is: what is the best way to do so? Will I need to create separate html/css files for each individual page? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, it would be good if start working in same directory containing different HTML files. Here I would provide you a small example. Create two web pages in same folder: page1.html and page2.html. Code for page1.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my first web app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3> this is page 1</h3>
    <a href="page2.html">Go to page2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and code for page2.html would be:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my first web app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3> this is page 2</h3>
    <a href="page1.html">Go to page1</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Likewise you can browse within multiple web pages.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to separate your CSS from the HTML, one of the advantages is that you may want to include the CSS stylesheet in another HTML page.

Comment: Thank you. I have separated my HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fine question.

Project structures will be different for everyone and every project but usually you have a folder for each page on your site with an index.html inside of it. This is because you want google.com/ instead of google.com/index.html. It is likely that your server is setup to read index.html files by deafault if you point a link to the folder. Does that make sense?

You could also name each page puppy.html and cat.html and then link them mypage.com/puppy.html and mypage.html/cat.html

Comment: Thank you. It does make a lot of sense.